# Express and socket.io chat?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express

I can set up the chat no problem, but my question is how do I get the chat to work on the default `port:80` where my main site is?

First thing that comes to mind is `iframing` it?

Here is my server.js code, one thing to note I don't really like `jade` so I am going to convert that into plain HTML. Also for the chat to work it has to be on any port other than `:80` so I am not quite sure how to get it to work on that main port, other than iframing?

So my question is obviously what are my options in getting the express server to work on the main port?

```
// Start server
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = 3700;

// Directory 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/chat'));


// Socket.io integration
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));


// Render content
app.set('views', __dirname + '/tpl');
app.set('view engine', "jade");
app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express);
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("page");
});


// Recieve msg and send
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('message', { message: 'welcome to the chat' });
    socket.on('send', function (data) {
        io.sockets.emit('message', data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Consider running your entire site via Node.js on port 80

Comment: If so, I may have to open a new question or change this one. It seems easy but I am not sure how to do that. Do I render the jade template with all the main html code including the chat html code. That makes sense, but can you run an express server on :80 I tried and it said its in use.

Comment: What I mean is basically render the chat box how I am doing but add all the code from the main index.html and merge it with the chat box html. Then serve that page instead, currently running on port:3700, I am not sure how I could change it to the default:80, is that even possible?

Comment: In order to run a Node.js server on port 80, you must kill your existing server on Port 80.  You can also configure your server to forward some requests to Node.js on a different internal port.

Comment: Oh okay, so by default lets say in wamp/localhost the config is set to run on port:80. I need to kill/stop that from being the default then use the same express server logic on port:80? Ill google where that config operation takes place, but if you know feel free to share :)

Comment: So I opened apache httpd.conf and see the line `#Listen x.x.x.x:80
Listen 80` do I comment out or change it, I say it should be commented out?

Comment: Looks like thats close, I run the express server on :80 and get `Cannot GET /mystuff/source/`, this is the result after erasing those lines in httpd.conf and changing my server.js to listen on port :80

Comment: Lastly I want to add one more thing. It works on http://127.0.0.1/ so I need some re-configuring of my stuff. So this seems like a nice solution, I am up for any others that may be easier, seems like I framing might be easier?

Comment: You need to set up Express to serve the rest of your site (probably with more `static()`s)

Answer (score 0):

You dont realy  need node-expres-jade on the port 80 for these aproach.

Node can just run the socket server (alone). Forget express/jade here.

And apache or nginx can handle all de client-side files (html, js , css ...).

add the  `var socket = io.connect('httt://yoururl:port');` on any html an it should work.

Comment: Sounds cool let me give it a shot, as of now I just iframed it and it works fine, but I think it would be better to just render it directly without the use of iframe.

Comment: just translate the jade  to  html, and send it to apache dir.

Comment: What does the `socket` variable replace in my original code. I am not sure?

Comment: is in the client side js.

Comment: I get `io is not defined`, I obviously am not understanding something here. I can feel we are close. I added the needed HTML to my index.html I added `var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:80')` to client side js, and included that client js script in my index.html. Maybe I need to load that script in the head perhaps? Or maybe need to understand how to get apache involved? Edit: adding to the head did not work lol thought Id try.

Comment: I just thought about it maybe I need to include `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` I forgot to do that.